# Load html in div and then remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load, webaddress

I'm a beginner in Javascript and I struggle with a problem for a while. I want to open a new content in an existing `div` from another local html document. So in main content I have a simple list of projects and when I click on one project I want it to open in same the `div` '#content' as my projects. For this I use code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.th-link').click(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').html('<h4>Loading...</h4>').load(url+ '#mynewdiv');
        $.getScript('js/jquery.js'); 
        $.getScript('js/jquery.horizontal.scroll.js'); 
        $.getScript('js/jquery.mousewheel.js'); 
        $(url).remove();
        return false;
    });
 });
```

The problem is when I want to go back to my main `div` with projects '#content', with back-button on mouse or with browser, I stuck on other `div` '#mynewdiv', or I get to the previous open site.
Can anybody help with the code?

I'm still dealing with this problem. I found a rough example that is similar to mine and I have transformed it, to work like I want, but still doesn't work as it should. To refresh my problem.

I want to open in certain div, a new html page and it will work back button.

I also tried benalman bbq but I can't figure out, what I'm doing wrong.

Here is what I'm doing

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.4.1");
    </script>
    <script src="jquery.address-1.1.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    $("document").ready(function(){

        function loadURL(url) {
            console.log("loadURL: " + url);
            $("#area").load(url);
        }


        // Event handlers
        $.address.externalChange(function(event) {
console.log("init: " + $('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
$("#area").load($('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
}).change(function(event) {
console.log("change");
});

        $('a.test').click(function(){
            loadURL($(this).attr('href'));
        });

        });

    /*]]>*/
    </script>

<style type="text/css">
#area {border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
height:300px;
width:100%;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<p>Test</p>
    <div id="area">

    <a class='test' href="test1.html" rel="address:/test1">Test 1</a> <br />
    <a class='test' href="test2.html" rel="address:/test2">Test 2</a> <br /> <br /> <br />

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the answer

Comment: Javascript changes will loss, when you press back button in browser

Answer (score 0):

`.load()` gets the data and displays it on the same site. The browser is never changing page. So when you click back, the browser will go to the previous open site.

You can use a plugin like [jQuery Address](https://github.com/asual/jquery-address) to simulate the behavior you want.